# Linq to Entities - Contar elementos de uma query que referencie dois contextos

Tags: c#, query, linq, linq-to-entities

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
var query = (from q1 in query1
            join q2 in query1 on q1.idGenerico equals q2.idGenerico into q2Left
            from q2 in q2Left.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join q3 in query3 on q2.idGenerico equals q3.idGenerico  into q3Left
            from q3 in q3Left.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { q1, q2, q3});
```

Basicamente ela é uma query para agrupar outras, que são de contextos diferentes, a partir dela eu tenho que pegar o total de registros resultantes desse agrupamento, e popular uma lista de objetos que serão retornados pelo método da query.

meu problema é: Ao tentar fazer qualquer tipo de manipulação com a query, eu recebo a seguinte excessão:

> “The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts”

no SO eu encontrei a seguinte resposta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332920/error-the-specified-linq-expression-contains-references-to-queries-that-are-as) que se encaixa no meu caso:

> If they're on different databases but on the same instance, create a
>   view on one of the databases that selects from the table on the other
>   database, then add the local table and view to a single EDMX.

minha pergunta é: quais outras soluções eu tenho para esse problema? sou obrigado a criar uma view?

Comment: Não recomendo em casos de grande massa de dados, mas desde que você traga para memória o resultado das duas queries, os contextos se tornam irrelevantes.

Comment: O problema é exatamente esse, a massa de dados tem que ser levada em conta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu reunião com um desenvolvedor mais experiente foi encontrada a seguinte solução:

Primeiramente eu consegui reduzir uma das querys por já existir uma view em banco com os dados da terceira.

Trabalhando com duas querys, de contextos diferentes, para pegar o total de registros (para paginar) e apenas uma amostra de registros (elementos de uma página) as consultas foram executadas na seguinte ordem:

1 - Executo a primeira query, atribuindo-a a um objeto Iqueryable.

2 - Aplico os filtros á primeira query (como são filtros dinâmicos, que podem ou não estarem preenchidos, não posso aplicá-los na consulta).

3 - Trago para uma Lista (LINQ To Objects) a chave que irá fazer o join entre os dois contextos. ex: query1.select(x => x.idTabelaOutroContexto).ToList();

4 - Executo a segunda query com base na lista acima.

5 - Aplico os filtros, também dinâmicos á segunda query.

6 - Atualizo a lista com as chaves com base dos registros da segunda query filtrada.

7 - Filtro a primeira query baseada na lista atualizada.

8 - Agora que filtrei a primeira query com base no retorno da segunda, alcanço o primeiro objetivo, o total de registros.. que é o count da primeira.

9 - Recolho as amostras das duas querys separadas trazendo para memória.

10 - Faço uma terceira query agrupando as listas criadas a partir da consulta das duas primeiras, e alcanço o segundo objetivo, que era coletar a amostra de dados.

Comment: O objeto iqueryable deve ficar enorme, mas a consulta é executada rapidamente e atende.